# What are the possible ways to debug when clause in Drools?

Tags: drools, drools-flow

I know we can add breakpoints in the consequences of a rule, but how can we debug the when clause ? my rule is not verified i wanna know why.
Please help

Comment: Debug in what way? Do you want to figure out why a rule has matched?

Comment: to figure out why a rule didn't match, specially with multiple conditions in the when part.

Answer (score -1):

Use `DebugAgendaEventListener`

Take a look at [this](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2016/08/12/get-it-done-with-these-5-techniques-to-debug-your-jboss-brms-applications/) blog post